# asp.net automatically refreshes when screen is clicked ,unwanted behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am working on a asp.net project and on one of my pages if i click anywhere on the body of the webpage the page is refreshed. The page is an admin area for adding and editing products if I click on a textbox to edit the page autmomatically refreshes and nothing can go into the textboxes. this doesnt happen on any of my other pages just on this one page and nothing i can see is different that would cause such a behaviour.
Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated 
thank you

I've looked at my other pages to see if there is a difference that would cause this behaviour and nothing seems different

**Content Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">



    <asp:Panel runat="server" class = "ProductList">
        <div id="products">

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item ID</th>
                        <th>Brand</th>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>image</th>
                        <th>Item Description</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Delete Product</th>
                        <th>Edit Product</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptAdminProducts" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%#Eval ("ItemID") %></td>
                            <td><%#Eval("Brand") %></td>
                            <td><%#Eval("Title") %></td>

                            <td>
                                <img src='data:image/jpg:base64,
                                <%#Eval("ProdImage") != System.DBNull.Value ? 
                                Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ProdImage")): String.Empty%> '
                                    alt="Prod image" />
                            </td>

                            <td><%#Eval("ItemDesc") %></td>
                            <td>€  <%#Eval("Price") %></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteProduct" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you Sure you want to delete this Product from the store ?')" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>' Text="Delete Product From Store" OnCommand="btnDeleteProduct_Command" CommandName="Delete" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnEditProduct" OnClick="btnEditProduct_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>' Text="Edit Product Details" OnCommand="btnEditProduct_Command" CommandName="Edit" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id ="addNewProductArea">
        <h1>Add Product</h1>


        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelNewProduct">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNewProdName" Text="Product Name"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNewProdName"></asp:TextBox>

            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNewProdBrand" Text="Product Brand"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNewProdBrand"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNewProdDesc" Text="Product Desc"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNewProdDesc"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNewProdPrice" Text="Product Price"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNewProdPrice"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fProdImage" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNewProdImage" Text="Upload product"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <div id="EditProducts">
        <h2>Edit Product Area</h2>
        <asp:Panel ID="panEditProduct" runat="server">

            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEditItemId" Text="Item ID"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGetItemID"></asp:Label>
            <br />
           <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEditBrand" Text="Product Brand"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEditBrand"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBrandError"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEditTitle" Text="Product Name"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEditTitle"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEditDesc" CssClass= "TextBoxLarge" Text="Product Description"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEditDesc"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEditPrice" Text="Product Price"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEditPrice" ></asp:TextBox>
            <br />


            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdateItem" Text="Update Product" OnClick="btnUpdateItem_Click" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Master page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="MasterAdmin.master.cs" Inherits="CA4KevinColgan10029059.MasterAdmin" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/AdminStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <header>
            <img src="images/Logo.png" />


            <nav>
                <ul class="menuarea">
                    <li><a class="navBarLink" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a class="navBarLink" href="Eleiko.aspx">Eleiko Barbells</a></li>
                    <li><a class ="navBarLink" href="SBD.aspx">SBD</a></li>
                    <li><a class ="navBarLink" href="Cart.aspx">Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a class ="navBarLink" href="AdminPage.aspx"</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="cart">

                    <asp:Label runat ="server" ID="lblItems"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal"></asp:Label>
                </div>

            </nav>

        </header>

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>





    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"... if I click on a textbox to edit ..."_ What about the textboxes for the Add form? or is it just the edit textboxes? What happens when you click the `btnEditProduct` button to edit a product? Can you share the code-behind for this page?

Comment: its the whole page contained within the body tag that is affected, i went to my css and changed the body width to give space between the borders of the browser window and the body. outside of the body area there is no issue